# How to create twitter new application using localhost address in website

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to create twitter developer application. I am trying `http://localhost:45896` in website field

Error :
The form has become outdated.
OR redirect to me login page.

Any Solution create application using localhost address.

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Answer (score 0):

Interms of using 'localhost' try your IP address like this

```
       **for ex:** http://123.0.0.1:45896/urpage.extension
```

Comment: it means that no solution create application with localhost address

Comment: yes.u cannot simply provide it as localhost, as it may conflict some others.